# CountIfs range <> to cell

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to make this work;

`=Countifs(P$1:P2,<>P1)`

Essentialy, counting the row if P2 does not match the one above.

It's giving me an error though.

Answer (score 0):

there's `=COUNTIF(range, criterion)` with single condition :

[Countif](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)

there's `=COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])` with multiple conditions

[Countifs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)

I think your formula should be :

```
=Countifs(P$1:P2,"<>"&P1)
```